# Umbraco: Changing the MemberType of an existing Member

Tags: c#, umbraco

In my Umbraco configuration, I have a member who is created with one associated MemberType, but administrators need to be able to move them to a different MemberType without losing the user's credentials so just creating a new Member would - as far as I can tell - probably not work for this.

I can do this:

```
Member ourMember = Member.GetAllAsList().Where(x => x.Id == memberId).First();
ourMember.ContentType = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.ContentType.GetByAlias(newMemberType);
ourMember.Save();
```

However, saving does not change the `ContentType` and the properties of the old `ContentType` persist on the member while it exists. Presumably there is some different way of making this change? Otherwise is there a way to transfer the `MembershipUser` to a new Member without losing the login credentials?

I realise I should possibly be using the `ContentService` for this but I can't find much useful information about how to do that and there is at least *some* regarding the old approach.

Also I can't help but feel that this way of getting a Member by Id is a terrible idea, but I couldn't see an easier one straight off.

Answer (score 1):

Membership in Umbraco is not as great as it could be. I'm pretty sure that you can't change a Member type just as you can't change the document type of some content.

I think you'll have to have a single standard membership type and then manage the type of user through membership groups (roles). If your different types of user need to have different data held against them then I suggest that you either create a union of all those fields and seperate them by tabs, or store that data in external DB tables. Also each standard .NET MembershipProvider has to be tied to a Member type in the web.config, from recollection.

The Content Service is for content only. Darren Ferguson re-wrote the Membership API recently so you'll need to check what version that is and compare it to your version to see which API is best used. I don't think the new API will allow this either.

I could be wrong but I think new Member(id) will return the member with that Id.

Finally you may get a better response on our.umbraco.com, rather than StackOverflow.

Best of luck!

Comment: I asked this one on our.umbraco.com which is a great place to find out things you already know, but a terrible place for new information. Unfortunately the entire member system relies on MemberTypes so I am stuck with that part of the process. I can probably make Umbraco do what I want, but I was hoping there might be a way I could avoid bending it too badly out of shape to get there.